# Check from Python script Raspberry´s power status

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Is there an equivalent to the yellow lightning on screen, or the red PWR LED blinking, that can be used from a Python script to know if there are power issues with a Raspberry?

Thanks!

Comment: A ping will you let know that the red LED is blinking? How? I said "power issues", which is what the LED blink and the on-screen lightning are meant to tell.

Comment: This may help... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91433/43814

Comment: Excellent @MarkSetchell! So I guess that when using **/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd get_throttled**, a return value of 0x50000 means "low voltage has happened", and 0x50001 means "it is happening now", right? Thanks for the info!

Comment: I am not 100% certain because I haven't tested it myself. If it works you can write it up and accept it as the correct answer so other folk know it works. Good luck.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks again. I don´t know how to write it up. You mean answering my own question with this info? I´m quite new to SO.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting you write and test the script and if it works as hoped, answer your own question and accept it as correct for extra points too. If it doesn't work, click `edit` under your original question and add what you tried and see if anyone can help further.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @MarkSetchell (thanks!), this works. I´ve tested it on a RPI 3B+ with some power supply issues:

```
import subprocess

pt = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd', 'get_throttled'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(res,err) = pt.communicate()
res = res.decode().split("=")[1]
res = res.rstrip("\n")
print ("Current Power Issues?    = ",(int(res,0) & 0x01) == 0x01)
print ("Any Power issues before? = ",(int(res,0) & 0x50000) == 0x50000)
```

Comment: Cool - well done and thank you for sharing back with the SO community. By the way, rather than testing for equality with the magic numbers which you had to repeat, you could test more simply for non-zero, that is `(int(res,0) & 0x50000) != 0`